# How to access values returned by onDataChange after the its completion?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am struggling to access the information returned from the database with `onDataChange`. I know it is due to its asynchronous nature, but I need to have these values stored somewhere to be accessed after the code is completed.

I have stored in the Firebase database a `user` child that stores `lat` and `lng` positions. My code then retrieves it as follows:

```
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    var user: User?

    dataSnapshot.children.forEach {
        user = it.getValue(User::class.java)
        Log.d("Maps::user::lat", user?.lat.toString()) // Has info
        Log.d("Maps::user::lng", user?.lng.toString()) // Has info
        mMyLocation.latitude = user!!.lat!!
        mMyLocation.longitude = user!!.lng!!
    }
}

val location = LatLng(mMyLocation.latitude, mMyLocation.longitude) // 0.0 and 0.0
```

The app has more than my location, but also other markers on the map. If I move all the code to show my location to inside the method, the other markers set up in `onMapReady` will not be shown. I need suggestions on how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First simply declare a gloabl (witin class)marker reference

```
lateint var myLocMarker:Marker
```

then add your location marker in google map (onmapready etc)

```
var a = MarkerOptions()
    .position(LatLng(50,6))) // any position, which you already have, i suppose 
myLocMarker = map.addMarker(a)
```

then inside `onDataChange` update the marker positions as

```
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    var user: User?

    dataSnapshot.children.forEach {
        user = it.getValue(User::class.java)
        Log.d("Maps::user::lat", user?.lat.toString()) // Has info
        Log.d("Maps::user::lng", user?.lng.toString()) // Has info
        mMyLocation.latitude = user!!.lat!!
        mMyLocation.longitude = user!!.lng!!
        myLocMarker.setPosition(LatLong(user!!.lat!!,user!!.lng!!))
    }
}
```

Comment: It works like this, but the other markers are still not set. I will certainly use another `onDataChange`. Is it OK to have more than 2? I will set as correct because it solved my location.

Comment: yes you can have more than one data change though you can also apply listner on some root note to fetch data and i not sure why there's an issue with other markers, as you know, we can add as many markers as you want, you just need to have the right lat long. glad that i could help, happy coding

Comment: I really need to make the results incoming from `onDataChange` to be available outside its scope because in the `onCreate`, as a dummy test, I set up hardcoded values of my own location, and from that location, I check if the other dummy locations are within the configured radius. Since the attempt to assign the incoming latitude and longitude to my `Location` variable will result null once it goes out of the scope, the other markers won't show.